# How to reset a loop jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

Ok, I've created a div dynamically in jQuery to display some blogposts.

```
<div class="blog-items">
    <div class="blog-item"></div>
</div>
```

The jQuery below adds a class of nomargin to remove the margin on the last block. How can I reset the loop so it starts again on a new row. Currently the nomargin class is applied to the remaining blocks.

Here's the jQuery excerpt

```
var blogItemLength = $('.blog-item').length;
if(blogItemLength > 2) {
    $('.blog-item:gt(1)').removeClass("blog-item").addClass("blog-item_nomargin");
}
```

Hope that makes sense, thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to add the `blog-item_nomargin` class to only the last element with the `.blog-item` class-name?

Comment: replace `gt(1)` with `last`

Comment: yeah that's right. There are 3 divs with class blog-item and I need the last one to have the blog-item_nomargin class. There are 9 divs in total, so 3 rows of 3 and every third one in the row need that class added. Thanks

Comment: using last didn't work unfortunately. Thing is, there are 9 generated  divs (3 on each line) with the class blog-item. Each 3rd one needs to have the nomargin class. Can the if statement be looped or reset to start again on each row somehow?

Comment: could it be something to do with the each() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest, from what little I understand of your problem:

```
$('.blog-item').filter(function(i){
    return (i + 1)%3 === 0;
}).removeClass('blog-item').addClass('blog-item_nomargin');
```

This takes all the `.blog-item` elements, filters them to keep only the third, sixth, ninth... elements, removes the `blog-item` class-name and adds the `blog-item_nomargin` class-name.

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the jquery question because I haven't understood precisely what you are trying to achieve.

But have you considered using CSS selectors? If you want to style your last .blog-item differently, you can use:

```
.blog-item:last-child {
    color: red; /* or whatever */
}
```

For other more complex scenarios, there is :nth-last-child()

Answer (score 0):

Using the `last()` selector is clearer than the `gt()` (greater than) selector:

```
$('.blog-item').last().removeClass("blog-item").addClass("blog-item_nomargin");
```

But if you must use `gt()`:

```
$('.blog-item:gt(-2)').removeClass("blog-item").addClass("blog-item_nomargin");
```

Please note that if you have multiple div.blog-items elements in your page you may need to do something like this:

```
$('.blog-items').each(function(index){
    $(this).children('.blog-item').last().removeClass("blog-item").addClass("blog-item_nomargin");
});
```

References

http://api.jquery.com/last/
http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Comment: thanks all and sorry for the vague q, think I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood of your problem I tried this :

```
var blogItemLength = $('.blog-item').length;
 $('.blog-items').each(function () {
  if(blogItemLength > 2) {
   $(this).find('.blog-item').last().removeClass("blog-item").addClass("blog-item_nomargin");
 }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/steo/BEmjA/  (I just used some sample class.)

The code I wrote changes the `class` of the third item for each group of `blog-items`

Hope this makes sense.